# getSelection without alt attribute and scripts in it?

Tags: javascript, getselection

I'm using window.getSelection () to get the selected text.
But, if i select an image too, it returns also altof an image.

EXAMPLE:

```
<img src="someSrc.jpg" alt="image_alt" /> My text here ...
```

if i select an image too, it returns

> image_alt My text here ...

But i need only

> My text here ...

Is there any way to get only text, without alt?

Thanks much

Comment: have you considered changing it to use the `alt` attribute?

Comment: i'll use it in open source project, so i need to strip all anwanted attributes.

Comment: what browsers are doing this?

Comment: tested in firefox. (i'm sorry, it returns alt attribute, not title, but that's not important, i think:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the `toString()` method of selection's Range(s), which is what `window.getSelection().toString()` is specified to do in the current version of [WHATWG's new Range spec](http://html5.org/specs/dom-range.html#apis-for-the-browsing-context-selection%3a-the-selection-interface) (although this is [contrary to what some browsers do](http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10583) and may or may not change). The following will work with multiple selected ranges (which Mozilla supports) and also in IE < 9.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/HkP2S/

Code:

```
function getSelectionRangeText() {
    var selText = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection(), rangeCount = sel.rangeCount;
        if (rangeCount) {
            for (var i = 0, rangeTexts = []; i < rangeCount; ++i) {
                rangeTexts.push("" + sel.getRangeAt(i));
            }
            selText = rangeTexts.join("");
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        selText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return selText;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This solution includes text inside `<script>` and `<style>` elements. To remove this, you could use `cloneContents()` on the selection ranges and traverse the DOM of the resulting document fragments, collecting text only from text nodes not contained within `<script>` and `<style>` elements. You could also expand on this to remove text that is inside elements with CSS `display: none`.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/HkP2S/2/

Code:

```
function getSelectionRangeText() {
    var selText = "", selTextParts = [];

    function getNodeText(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            selTextParts.push(node.data);
        } else if (node.hasChildNodes()
        && !(node.nodeType == 1 && /^(script|style)$/i.test(node.tagName))) {
            for (var child = node.firstChild; !!child; child = child.nextSibling) {
                getNodeText(child);
            }
        }
    }

    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection(), rangeCount = sel.rangeCount;
        if (rangeCount) {
            for (var i = 0; i < rangeCount; ++i) {
                getNodeText(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            selText = selTextParts.join("");
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        selText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return selText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much. But there is a problem with inline scripts(javascript, css). it takses it too. Whan can be done to prevent it?

Comment: @Syom: That's true. You'd have the same problem with the `cloneContents()` / `textContent` solution in the other answer. If that's a problem for you then you could use `cloneContents()` and manually walk the DOM. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Well, I just gave the idea :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
window.getTextSelection = function() {
    //First get HTML Fragment of selection
    var html = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents(); 
    //Return only the text
    return html.textContent||html.innerText;
}
```

In some cases you can simply disable the user selection via CSS:
May you also can achieve this by disabling user-select for images:

```
img {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: hmmmm, it returns [object DocumentFragment]

Comment: `return window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString()` would be simpler and better, although you should also check the `rangeCount` property of the selection is non-zero. Also, Mozilla allows multiple ranges per selection for cases like selecting table columns, although I don't think it's widely used and the feature will possibly be removed from Mozilla in future.