# getSelection.toString() - without using toString()?

Tags: javascript, selection, getselection

I need to extract text from a selection and send it to a TTS service. The TTS service will return a stream URL and a set of indices for each word, indicating where they start and end (in both time and text).

When the user plays the stream I want to highlight each word as they are read out. To do that I can't just use the text indices for each word, because they can not get me back to the original HTML nodes - hence why I can't use `toString()` which is strictly text.

What I'm doing so far is creating a TreeWalker using the start and end containers of the range object and using that to extract all the text nodes in the range.

**Problem:**
`window.getSelection().toString()` inherently ignores nodes that are not displayed. That includes `<script>` nodes, `<style>` node, nodes with `display: none;` and the likes. Using TreeWalker doesn't.

I know I can manually skip all of these nodes in the TreeWalker (like suggested in [getSelection without alt attribute and scripts in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256608/getselection-without-alt-attribute-and-scripts-in-it)), but it can become quite complex really fast (especially checking the visibility of each node).

Before going into this I wanted to ask, if there are any new methods or libraries available that have emerged since the question I linked was answered?

I don't intend the code to be cross browser and I'm using plain Javascript (i.e. no jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would now recommend against using `window.getSelection().toString()`. Its behaviour varies between browsers and there is [currently no spec for it](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#dom-selection-stringifier). There was a draft version of the HTML5 spec that mandated that it should return a conatenation of the results of calling `toString()` on each selection range, which is what IE 9 implemented; WebKit and Mozilla both do something more complicated. Further, there are differences between what WebKit and Mozilla do, and they could change their implementations at any time.

At the risk of promoting my own stuff, you may be able to use the [TextRange module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule) of my [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy) library, which attempts to provide ways to navigate the DOM and ranges within it as text the user sees. The alternative is doing a lot of similar work yourself or limiting the HTML that your code can work with.

Comment: The code is only used in a Chrome extension, so the lack of cross browser support isn't much of an issue. Anyway, is there a non-minified version of Rangy/TextRange module? I've got a working solution now, but interested in seeing how you've done it.

Comment: @Woodgnome: The lack of spec is still an issue for the long term: Chrome's implementation could easily change in the future. Source for TextRange module is here: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/js/modules/rangy-textrange.js, plus Rangy 1.3 builds have minified and unminified versions of everything.

Comment: Good point with regard to the implementation - it was just a temporary solution, so should be ok either way.

Comment: I've looked through the code and I'm not entirely sure I can get back from a character index of the text to the corresponding HTML node. I've upvoted your response anyway as it's a very useful library. Also posted the code from my own solution (in it's current state).

Comment: @Woodgnome: You can. `selectCharacters()` and `toCharacterRange()`. See http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule

Comment: Ah yes, I get it now. Is the non-minified code of TextRange up to date (it seems to create an exception when used instead of the minified code presented on your TextRange demo page)?

Comment: @Woodgnome: It should be, although the source has logging calls in that will break things in the absence of the logging library I use (the logging calls are removed in the build step). I'm pretty sure the last release works.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for answers I started writing my own parser. It's a bit crude as there is **no cross browser support** and I don't do any modifications to the text - this means any linebreaks and other whitespace from the HTML will be preserved.

There is also a lot of redundancy which I haven't cleaned up yet, such as traversing children of nodes I already know to be hidden.

Anyway, the code:

```
function ParsedRange(range){
  this.text = "";
  this.nodeIndices = [];

  this.highlight = function(startIndex, endIndex){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var startNode = this.nodeIndices[startIndex].node;
    var endNode = this.nodeIndices[endIndex].node;
    var startOffset = startIndex - this.nodeIndices[startIndex].startIndex;
    var endOffset = endIndex - this.nodeIndices[endIndex].startIndex + 1;

    // Scroll into view
    startNode.parentNode.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();

    // Highlight
    range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
    range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  };

  // Parsing starts here
  var startIndex;
  var rootNode = range.commonAncestorContainer;
  var startNode = range.startContainer;
  var endNode = range.endContainer;
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(rootNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT | NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false); // Only walk text and element nodes
  var currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode;

  // Move to start node
  while (currentNode && currentNode != startNode) currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();

  // Extract text
  var nodeText;
  while (currentNode && currentNode != endNode){ // Handle end node separately
    // Continue to next node if current node is hidden
    if (isHidden(currentNode)){
      currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
      continue;
    }

    // Extract text if text node
    if (currentNode.nodeType == 3){
      if (currentNode == startNode) nodeText = currentNode.nodeValue.substring(range.startOffset); // Extract from start of selection if first node
      else nodeText = currentNode.nodeValue; // Else extra entire node

      this.text += nodeText;
      if (currentNode == startNode) startIndex = range.startOffset * -1;
      else startIndex = this.nodeIndices.length;
      for (var i=0; i<nodeText.length; i++){
        this.nodeIndices.push({
          startIndex: startIndex,
          node: currentNode
        });
      }
    }

    // Continue to next node
    currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
  }

  // Extract text from end node if it's a text node
  if (currentNode == endNode && currentNode.nodeType == 3 && !isHidden(currentNode)){
    if (endNode == startNode) nodeText = currentNode.nodeValue.substring(range.startOffset, range.endOffset); // Extract only selected part if end and start nodes are the same
    else nodeText = currentNode.nodeValue.substring(0, range.endOffset); // Else extract up to where the selection ends in the end node

    this.text += nodeText;
    if (currentNode == startNode) startIndex = range.startOffset*-1;
    else startIndex = this.nodeIndices.length;
    for (var i=0; i<nodeText.length; i++){
      this.nodeIndices.push({
        startIndex: startIndex,
        node: currentNode
      });
    }
  }

  return this;
}
ParsedRange.removeHighlight = function(){
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
};

function isHidden(element){
  // Get parent node if element is a text node
  if (element.nodeType == 3) element = element.parentNode;

  // Only check visibility of the element itself
  if (window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("visibility") == "hidden") return true;

  // Check display and dimensions for element and its parents
  while (element){
    if (element.nodeType == 9) return false; // Document
    if (element.tagName == "NOSCRIPT") return true;

    if (window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("display") == "none") return true;
    if (element.offsetWidth == 0 || element.offsetHeight == 0){ // If element does not have overflow:visible it is hidden
      if (window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("overflow") != "visible"){
        return true;
      }
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I've made it as a class (apart from the `isHidden()` helper function) due to the way it's integrated in my project.

That aside the class works by passing it a valid range which it will then extract the text inside the range and save references to all the nodes. These references are used in the `highlight()` function, which uses browser selection to highlight based on start and end character indices.

An extra note on the `nodeIndices` property (seeing as that might not make sense). `nodeIndices` is an array containing objects with the form:

```
{
  startIndex: // Int
  node: // Reference to text node
}
```

For every single character I extract into my resulting text I push one of those objects on `nodeIndices`, the `node` property is simply a reference to the text node, from which the text came. `startIndex` defines at which character the node begins in the entire text.

Using this array I can translate from a character index in `ParsedParagraph.text` to an HTML node and the index of the corresponding character inside that node.

**Example of use:**

```
// Get start/end nodes and offsets for range  
var startNode = // Code to get start node here, can be a text node or an element node
var startOffset = // Offset into the start node
var endNode = // Code to get end node here, can be a text node or an element node
var endOffset = // Offset into the end node

// Create the range
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);

// Parse the range using the ParsedRange class
var parsedRange = new ParsedRange(range);


parsedRange.text; // Contains visible text with whitespaces preserved.
parsedRange.highlight(startIndex, endIndex); // Will highlight the corresponding text inside parsedRange.text using browser selection
```